# XML DOM and javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, xmldom

I am getting a childnodes undefined error when executing the below code.  What am I doing wrong?  Also, is there a better way of making this happen?

```
   var xmlhttp;

   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code fop=new XMLHr IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
         //document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;
         if (window.DOMParser)
         {
           parser=new DOMParser();
           xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(xmlhttp.responseText,"text/xml");

                       var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("STATUS");
        if(x[0].childNodes[0].wholeText == "notLoggedIn")
         {
            window.location='login.html';
         }
```

Comment: What does the returned XML look like?

Answer (score 0):

Last four lines of code must become as follows:

```
try {
    if(x[0].childNodes[0].wholeText == "notLoggedIn") {
        window.location='login.html';
    }
} catch(e) {
    // handle your error here
}
```